# What are these inputs for this audio power amplifier?

Tags: amplifier

I have made a preamplifier with filter but before asking that question I decided to open a specific question about a MOSFET audio power amplifier. It seems an old one and I cannot find its data-sheet so I couldn’t share it. Below is its right inputs and right outputs:

[image]

From its banana jack outputs it is powering a 8Ohm 60W speaker. Speaker is used for some experimental setup at low frequencies from 0.1Hz to 100Hz max.

I noticed that they are using **sym** input which is coming from a function generator set to much higher than line voltages like 1V. One of the reason is that same function generator output also goes to a scope and a DAQ. So basically they don’t use typical audio inputs.

The preamplifier I made will replace the function generator and will be coupled to sym input. But I don’t know the input impedance of this input.

Regarding the photo my question is; what is **sym** input used for? I couldn’t find what sym and asym stand for? And what can be the **ground lift** switch?

Comment: Symmetric and asymmetric.  Ground lift disconnects the ground pins on the input connectors from the amplifier's local ground, to reduce problems with ground loops in large venues.

Comment: Does that lift break the safety earth you mean?

Comment: Isnt that another way to say differential or balanced? Those are xlr differential connectors

Comment: @Passerby Can be but I don’t know. Can we find the voltage levels for these inputs?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but balanced audio is typically mic level voltage.

Comment: Im not sure I saw it can take like 2V.

Comment: If you posted some more photos (entire amp; front panel; entire back panel with any data label) we could have more info to help you out.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati The only extra photo I can find now is here https://picclick.de/ZOFFMUSIC-ZA200-Mosfet-Amplifier-Verst%C3%A4rker-Endstufe-322850318160.html

Comment: Can't you shoot a photo of the real thing? Haven't you access to the amplifier you describe? BTW, linking to external images is frowned upon here, since the links may rot and it involves extra steps and maybe access to cloud-based sites. The question should stand on its own feet as much as possible.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I could but right now Im not at that place. I can access on Monday.

Comment: OK. Try to do that when you can. It will help us a lot.

Comment: How far can the ground be lifted? until power transformer insulation arcs over?

Comment: XLRs are often used for line level signals, as well as for microphone levels. Pro consoles use XLRs for lline out to power amps and active speakers.  I'd guess that the XLR input on that amp is line level.  The XLR output may be line level or higher - the manual should provide the details.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRETb8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Possible internal wiring.*

- The asymmetrical input would be signal and ground - similar to a guitar jack.
- The symmetrical input would be for a differential signal - similar to a balanced microphone for low level signals or long distance. A transformer can be used to unbalance the input internally.
- Earth loops can be a problem with audio electronics. Typically this happens if two pieces of equipment are connected to mains earth but also connected to each other via a shielded cable. The earth lift switch breaks this loop by disconnecting the audio ground from the mains earth. The metal chassis would normally remain earthed.

The only problem with my last point is that the ASYM jack isn't isolated from the chassis which appears to be metal.

Comment: It looks like a rubber washer or insert on the asym jack.

Comment: Also, you don't address the question on possible voltage.

Comment: @Transistor I didnt know that the sym has input has such isolation. Does that also mean the transformet also filters DC bias if there is any?

Comment: @atomant: I don't know either. Transformer inputs were common forty years ago but it could be an op-amp differential input instead. The transformer is the easiest way to visualise the inputs but given that you say the frequency response goes down to 0.1 Hz the transformer input is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Asym (short for asymmetric) input is also known as an unbalanced input.

Sym (short for symmetrical) input is also known as a balanced input

The Unbalanced input most likely has an input sensitivity of either -10 dBu or -10 dBv (depending on the age of the amplifier and where it was manufactured) for full output.

The Balanced input most likely has an input sensitivity of +4 dBu for full output.